# If I install two video cards each with two monitor outputs does that mean I can connect up to 4 monitors and use them to display 4 different desktops?

Tags: display

If I ask two video cards each with two monitor outputs does that mean I can connect up to 4 monitors and use them to display 4 different desktops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is correct.  The amount of monitors that you can have connected to your system is limited to whether the video card supports multiple monitors and how many video card you can have installed.

If you are looking to utilize the monitors for further productivity, perhaps taking a look at [this](http://lifehacker.com/5616859/is-the-multiple+monitor-productivity-boost-a-myth) article on the myth of productivity of multiple monitors will help out as well.

Answer (score 3):

yes, but bear in mind if you wish to perform SLI or similar gaming setups by combining the 3D power of the two cards you can only run 2 monitors (both from one card) while that's turned on. You can turn it on and off without a reboot though.

Comment: Glad someone pointed this out.

Comment: Thanks. But the other person gave essential the same answer but was a tad earlier. To be fair I gave him/her the tick. :)